# Why can I create a reference to a value from a post-increment, but not from a pre-increment expression?

Tags: perl, reference, operators

```
% perl -e '$i = 9; $p = \$i++; $q = \++$i; $i = "WTF"; print "$$p $$q\n"'
9 WTF
```

I was expecting that both work the same and print `9 11`, since neither the pre- nor the post-increment could be used as lvalues in perl.

Is this described anywhere, has it any rationale, or it's just a glitch? All I could find was about the magical properties of the increment operator when applied to non-numeric strings, which seems totally unrelated.

Notice that this also applies to decrement operators, it's not a matter of operator precedence (adding parens or writing it as `($p, $q) = \($i++, ++$i)` does not change anything) and it's the same behaviour in older versions like perl 5.6.

I'm not asking about workarounds (I know about putting an `int` between the `\` and the `++`, or adding a zero, etc).

Comment: Instead of using a workaround to a workaround, do `\( my $anon = $i )` which clearly identifies your intent. Clarity is importing here since this is a really weird thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Post-decrement returns the old value of `$i`, so it must return a fresh scalar and does so.

Pre-decrement returns the new value of `$i`, so it simply returns `$i`. There's no point in building a new scalar for nothing.

Comment: Thanks that somehow makes sense implementation-wise, yet it still feels sketchy. Surely they could've caught it at compile time and only built the scalar if needed. Kind of similar cases are the `//`, `&&` and `||` operators.

Comment: Why? It mashes very lithe sense to take a ref to a scalar, and even less to an anonymous one. There's absolutely no point to add all that logic

Comment: slow down a bit with that one ;-) how about setting `$/` to record mode? or creating enum-like constant subs without building strings and evaluating them?. There are *plenty* of uses for refs to anonymous scalars (especially when you're using perl for one-liners and such). But in this case, I would've done the reverse -- I would've allowed for `++`, `--`, `//`, etc to be used as lvalues. Even if `$a++ = ...` does not make much sense with the default operators, it is very useful when `++` is overloaded. But I'll leave it here -- it was not my intention to start a what-if discussion.

Comment: Re "*slow down a bit with that one*", You just listed a two *rare* uses, and both are really bad features that have far better alternatives. So you're effectively jsut repeating what I said: It makes very little sense to use scalar references. // Re "*I would've allowed for ++, --, //, etc to be used as lvalues.*", That needlessly converts compile-time errors into run-time errors. BAD! There's a reason we have rvalues.

Comment: No, they don't have any better alternatives (there aren't actually any practical alternatives), unfortunately. And there are many other uses of a ref for sematic purposes (in core or elsewhere, like it or not). But you're veering this into a philosophical discussion about "good practices" and such -- basically about what *kind* of  inconsistency/non-orthogonality is *good* (as if there were any good kind of it, LOL)

Comment: Setting $/ to a ref and using readline is like using read with a number, except it breaks every other readline in the program. The official way of creating constants is with the constant module, which is better is every way.

Comment: `read` does not work with `ARGV` in the same way `<>` does, and `use constant` does internally the same thing you proscribe. And there are **many** reasons to want to reimplement `constant.pm` (with another name), like fixing its horrible syntax (to make it more enum-like and allowing simply copy-pasting from C headers) and having automatically generate reverse mappings from values to names.

Comment: Ah yes for `read ARGV`. Still, `$/ = \++$i;` makes no sense. And constant.pm does not use `\++$i`. You then listed reasons for creating constants, but not reasons for using scalar refs, so they're *completely* irrelevant. /// So, while you did managed to come up with a *single* example of useful use of a scalar reference, you have been *unable* to come up with any examples that would benefit at all from changing the current system, much less a reason that would warrant slowing down every Perl program and removing safety constraints.